# Different units for independent and dependent variable in a regression

Tags: regression

I'm running a regression: sleep on education.

The units on educ are years whereas the units on sleep are minutes per week. Therefore, I think a coefficient on education should be interpreted as units corresponding to minutes.

Suppose the coefficient is 5. Then, I will interpret the regression as an year increase in education should reduce sleep by 5 minutes per week. Is that the 
correct way to think about it?

Comment: Since coefficient is positive. You would say year increase in education increases sleep by 5 minutes/ week.

Comment: The units calculus tells us the coefficient is in units of minutes per week per year.  As far as your interpretation goes, it's not justified by the regression because it sounds *causal* whereas the regression is merely assessing an *association.*

Comment: @whuber Interesting. Does it necessarily have to be minutes per week, *per year*? Couldn’t it be a survey item response to a question regarding minutes slept in the past week? Just curious.

Comment: @Tom I don't understand your question, because the *source* of quantitative information doesn't have any bearing on the *units* in which it is expressed.

Comment: @whuber I was more focused on the ‘coefficient units’ in your comment. You indicated that the coefficient is in minutes per week, per year. Is the *per year* part referring to per year of education?

Comment: @Tom yes it is.  In general, in any equation $y = \ldots + \beta x + \ldots,$ the units of $\beta$ *must* be the units of $y$ divided by the units of $x.$  Here, the units of $y$ are minutes per week and the units of $x$ are years of education, whence the units of $\beta$ must be (minutes per week) divided by (years of education), which would routinely be expressed as "minutes per (week * year)" in the units calculus. These trivial observations clarify some questions that would seem to be statistical in nature: understanding units helps simplify the mathematics of statistical procedures.

Comment: @whuber Awesome. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you are considering only one independent variable $x_{i}$, and it’s effect on $y_{i}$, then your interpretation is sufficient. And yes, your interpretation is in the correct units. The unit increase in education should be expressed in *years*, while its effect on sleep should be expressed in *minutes per week*.

> I think a coefficient on education should be interpreted as units corresponding to minutes.

There is no requirement in a simple linear regression context that the units of your dependent variable must correspond to the units of your independent variable. You *could* scale your independent variable $x_{i}$, but it would sacrifice the interpretability of your slope coefficient. First, it is important to note that scaling the regressor affects your slope but leaves the intercept unchanged. The simple bivariate model is expressed as follows

$$
Y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}X + \epsilon,
$$

with each realization $x_{i}$ denoting an individual's *years* of education. To express years in *minutes*, you would scale (multiply) each $x_{i}$ by 525,600, which is precisely the number of minutes in a full calendar year. This does the following

$$
Y = \beta_{0} + \left(\frac{\beta_{1}}{c}\right) \left(X * c\right) + \epsilon
$$

where c is any arbitrary constant. Note, this will *not* affect your model fit or p-values. Should you scale your education variable accordingly and rerun your model, simply multiply the coefficient by the constant (i.e., 525,600) to arrive back at the slope coefficient associated with education expressed in yearly units.

Graphically, the scaling of the x-axis is affected. Now, a unit (minute) increase in education results in a smaller decrease in minutes slept per week. See the following two plots below which I created with simulated data. I jittered the points to avoid overlap. The first shows weekly minutes of sleep expressed as a function of education (years). See below:

[image]

The second plot scales education, which is now expressed in *minutes*. See below:

[image]

The intercept is the same. However, the slope will change. A unit (minute) increase in education is not associated with the same change in minutes slept per week. In essence, we simply 'chopped up' education into smaller equally sized units. Note, this interpretation is a bit awkward. Be mindful we are assuming education has a constant, linear relationship with sleep.

> Suppose the coefficient is 5. Then, I will interpret the regression as an year increase in education should reduce sleep by 5 minutes per week. Is that the correct way to think about it?

You indicated that weekly minutes of rest has a negative association with education. Thus, the coefficient on education *should* be $-5$, not $5$. Another way to think about it is the following: *two individuals differing in only one year of education would result in a 5-minute negative difference in weekly rest time*. In other words, more education is associated with less sleep, on average.

Also, as a simple bivariate regression, such a model *ignores* other variables that could partly explain this relationship.

In sum, you *can* have different units! The interpretation with education expressed in years is a bit cleaner.